# Create JQuery Event on Draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable

Check Image for the look of Carousel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1CKR.jpg

This is my Timeline Carousel And it works perfectly fine.

The problem occurs when I drag the Timeline Pointer (Yellow arrow) with in the time line and leave it in a different position, The images in the carousel (each image is in a < li > tag) moves accordingly by an Event. But the event is not triggered.

This is achieved using draggable function in Jquery with parent containment.

```
 $( "#timelinePosition" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" });
```

I am creating an event to move the Images in carousel to a particular left margin when the yellow pointer is clicked.

```
$('#timelinePosition').on('click', function() {draggablePosters ();});
```

This event either needs a click after dragging. While dragging if the mouse pointer moves out of the parent, the event does not occur.

http://jsfiddle.net/a6Uj5/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#timelinePointer").bind("drag", function (event, ui) {
    var pointerMargin = $('#timelinePointer').css("left");
    $('#posterImage').css("margin-left", pointerMargin);
});
```